# How to determine the missing class in ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jboss

I've recently refactored code in a service and on deployment to jboss I've started getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more from [Module "deployment.invstr-orders-1-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.loadSci(ServletContainerInitializerDeploymentProcessor.java:194)
    ... 7 more
```

I understand this problem is caused often by a dependency missing from the classpath of a java application, however I don't know how to determine what class it's failing to load? A look in the jboss logs reveals nothing further and that WAR is the main WAR of my application - it contains everything.

How can I determine what class isn't being loaded?